# Unable to apply ReactCSSTransitionGroup on "width" or "left" attributes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using `React` to animate the width of a `div` using their `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` addon. Please check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/11371/).

Clicking, every time on the red `div` will simulate a transition.

The `opacity` transition is working well in this case. However, any other properties like `width`, `height` or `left`,`top` (for absolutely positioned elements) is not working. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand exactly how `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` works before trying to use transitions that are more complex than opacity.

When you specify a transition name of `example`, the following steps occur when `render()` is called:

1. Component is rendered into DOM with class `example-enter`
2. Next tick: Component adds class `example-enter-active`
3. Next tick: `example-enter` and `example-enter-active` are removed from Component class.

When unmounting the component, these steps occur:

1. Component receives class `example-leave`
2. Next tick: Component removes class `example-leave` and adds class `example-leave-active`
3. Next tick: Component is removed from DOM

Because of the way these classes are added/removed, I've found it to be more intuitive to animate `max-width` or `max-height` instead of `width` or `height`.

I've edited your fiddle to give an example of this:

http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/11374/

Comment: I see, I will try applying this to other scenarios and report back.

Answer (score 0):

CSS properties you put in the `style` prop will be applied as inline styles and override properties defined in your stylesheet, unless you assign the later an `!important` flag.

In your case, the `width` and `height` CSS properties you set in javascript take precedence over the `width` and `height` you'll have defined in your stylesheet.

Comment: Is there a way to do `react` transitions with inline styling?

Comment: You could use [ReactTransitionGroup](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#low-level-api-reacttransitiongroup) directly.